# Why im getting java.io.FileNotFoundException, (No such file or directory) In Eclipse when trying the run the Testng.xml file

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, file-not-found, testng.xml

I'm trying to run the testng.xml in eclipse,(Why the / slashes is getting changed to \ slashes) I get the following file not found error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/nandhakumar/Desktop/Resources/Automation Workspace/liveproject1\src\main\java\resources\config.properties (No such file or directory)
```

The file path which is being fetched from the WebDriverInstance class for Config.properties but when i do the file path is getting changed to \ backslashes from src.(As i'm using mac i'm using forward slashes for giving file path).

**Attaching the WebDriverInstance class code where im giving the config.properties file path and browser paths:**

```
package base;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class WebDriverInstance {

    public static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        if (driver.get() == null) {
            try {
                driver.set(createDriver());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return driver.get();
    }

    public static WebDriver createDriver() throws IOException {
        WebDriver driver = null;

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream data = new FileInputStream(
                System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/java/resources/config.properties");
        prop.load(data);

        if (prop.getProperty("browser").equals("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/java/drivers/chromedriver");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else if (prop.getProperty("browser").equals("firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/java/drivers/geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } 
        
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return driver;
    }

    public static void cleanupDriver() {
        driver.get().quit();
        driver.remove();
    }

}
```

I guess due to this Testng Cannot instantiate class for the class which im trying to run
`org.testng.TestNGException:  Cannot instantiate class uk.co.automationtesting.AddRemoveItemBasketTest`

When I tried running it I got a FileNotFoundException.

How do I correctly specify the path?

**Will attach the Console error which i'm getting is there any other way to workaround this issue ?**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class uk.co.automationtesting.AddRemoveItemBasketTest
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor(InstanceCreator.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstanceUsingObjectFactory(InstanceCreator.java:113)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstance(InstanceCreator.java:79)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:25)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense(GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:112)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:165)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:122)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:102)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:94)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:59)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:463)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:339)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:292)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:223)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.ITestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(ITestRunnerFactory.java:55)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:659)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:173)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1300)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1276)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1125)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:23)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/nandhakumar/Desktop/Resources/Automation Workspace/liveproject1\src\main\java\resources\config.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
    at base.BasePage.<init>(BasePage.java:26)
    at base.Hooks.<init>(Hooks.java:12)
    at uk.co.automationtesting.AddRemoveItemBasketTest.<init>(AddRemoveItemBasketTest.java:24)
    ... 35 more
```

I tried the project -> clean , Maven -> clean , Maven ->update project and file.separator too  nothing worked it would be helpful if anyone can help with the solution.

Just wanted to know why the forward / slashes are getting changed to \ slashes even though i give correct file path,What wrong with this code ?

Comment: All those `System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/..."` instead of using a relative path (not starting with `/`) looks odd. In which directory is `config.properties` located?

Comment: It's located under the same directory that user.dir is to fetch details from the liveproject 1 this is the full path(/Users/nandhakumar/Desktop/Resources/Automation\ Workspace/liveproject1/src/main/java/resources/config.properties ), and as you can see in this path /src/main/java/resources/config.properties it comes under the resources folder

Comment: you should try using +File.separator+ instead of the "/"s.  Not sure why they're changing there...  but File.separator is nice because it'll stay platform independent.  So use File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator .+...

Comment: Does running a TestNG test give you a launch configuration you can edit? By default, some configurations use the workspace root as the working directory.

Comment: @pcalkins I have tried the File.separator it didn't work i'm getting the same Error. public static WebDriver createDriver() throws IOException {
  WebDriver driver = null;

  Properties prop = new Properties();
  
   String filePath=System.getProperty("user.dir") +  File.separator +
            "src" + File.separator +
            "main" + File.separator +
            "java" + File.separator +
            "resources" + File.separator +
            "config.properties";
   FileInputStream data = new FileInputStream(filePath);
  prop.load(data); // let me know if i'm doing it wrong ?

Comment: @nitind Running with TestNG test run configuration is there , it fetched details from that exact project level only which is liveproject1 its not fetching from any workspace root .

Comment: is it still showing the slashes being changed?  Is the path correct?  Your original error shows an odd path there... not only are the paths changed but it's a relative path.  I'd expect user.dir to be absolute.

Comment: @all thanks for everyones input i used try catch method to resolve it `try {
            prop.load(WebDriverInstance.class.getClassLoader().
                    getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }` // this is the code i have used made few changes in fileinputstream to getClassLoader